# Installer for Java Web Application

Tags: installation, windows-installer, web-platform-installer

I have developed Web Application in C#, ASP.NET and SQL Server Express Edition.

I have created installer (setup.exe) for the application using Visual Studio 2010.

This installer checks for prerequisites software like IIS, .NET Framework and SQL Server.

I have bundle all require software in installer and they get install on user machine if not installed.

I will be developing Web application using Structs2, Oracle, and Tomcat etc.

I want to create same installer like above for Structs2 application.

I am checking following softwares

Actual Installer, Advanced Installer, BitRock InstallBuilder, Inno Setup, Install Creator, Installer VISE for Windows, InstallShield, install4j, IzPack, NSIS, openInstaller, Scriptlogic MSI Studio, Smart Install Maker, Symantec Wise Installation Studio, and WiX.

Any idea what will be suitable software for above tasks?

- Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Advanced Installer you can use predefined wizards for creating setup packages for Java, Tomcat Web applications, etc... The support for prerequisites is very powerful and easy to use, providing a large number of predefined ones, but you can also create new ones with your custom settings.

It also allows you to execute SQL scripts using multiple configurations, even scripts with their content generated at install time.

Its GUI allows you to easily get along with the application without loosing any customization power, and its CLI (command line interface) allows you to automate your builds once you got them configured.